# Javascript function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my JavaScript, since I am trying to call a function but my web console tells me that is not defined. The function is in a seperate .js document where there are other JavaScript function which I am able to call without problems. It is only this first one.

This is my html:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="panel-style space table_space">
                <h3 class="heading-title">Klienter</h3>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table simple">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>CVR</th>
                                <th>Firmanavn</th>
                                <th>By</th>
                                <th>Kontaktperson</th>
                                <th>Direkte telefon</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="list_all_clients">
                            <script type="text/javascript">list_all_clients()</script>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the top of the HTML where I am including the functions:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <title></title>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.prettycheckable/prettycheckable.js'></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tipsy/tipsy.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.gmap/gmap3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/api_data.js"></script>

    <!--
    <script src="scripts/jquery.charts/morris.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.js"></script>
    -->

    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nvdcharts/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nvdcharts/nvd.js"></script>
    -->
```

This is my JavaScript document:

```
function list_all_clients(){

    var datastring = "get_all_clients=yes"

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "api.php",
        data : datastring,
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data) {
            $('#list_all_clients').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function add_client(){
        var cvr = $("input#cvr").val();
        var firmanavn = $("input#firmanavn").val();
        var hoved_tlf = $("input#hoved_tlf").val();
        var geo_omr = $("input#geo_omr").val();
        var vej = $("input#vej").val();
        var husnummer = $("input#husnummer").val();
        var by = $("input#by").val();
        var postnummer = $("input#postnummer").val();
        var land = $("input#land").val();
        var branche = $("input#branche").val();
        var ansatte = $("input#ansatte").val();
        var revenue = $("input#revenue").val();
        var bruttofortjeneste = $("input#bruttofortjeneste").val();
        var k_navn = $("input#k_navn").val();
        var k_stilling = $("input#k_stilling").val();
        var direkte_tlf = $("input#direkte_tlf").val();
        var direkte_email = $("input#direkte_email").val();

        var datastring = 'new_client=yes'+'&cvr='+cvr+'&firmanavn='+firmanavn+'&hoved_tlf='+hoved_tlf+'&geo_omr='+geo_omr+'+'&vej='+vej+'&husnummer='+husnummer+'&by='+by+'&postnummer='+postnummer+'&land='+land+'&branche='+branche+
        '&ansatte='+ansatte+'&revenue='+revenue+'&bruttofortjeneste='+bruttofortjeneste+'&k_navn='+k_navn+'&k_stilling='+k_stilling+'&direkte_tlf='+direkte_tlf+'&direkte_email='+direkte_email;

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "api.php",
            data : datastring,
            dataType : "html",
            success : function(data) {
                get_all_clients();
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: I think you forgot ' or extra ' in datastring variable. please check it.

Comment: "Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster", --> you're calling `list_all_clients()` in an inline script before it was loaded. Put the script tag loading the script containing `list_all_clients()` before line `<script type="text/javascript">list_all_clients()</script>`.

Comment: Putting it just before `</body>` did not work. Not sure what you mean about 'or extra'?

Comment: You've an inline script calling a function, if the script containing that function is loaded after the inline script calls that function, what you can expect? Also please tell exactly which function is not defined.

Comment: Put your external Js file on root level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
geo_omr+'+'&vej='
```

replace that with:

```
geo_omr+'&vej='
```

Also, make sure you've loaded the script that contains `list_all_clients()` in the page's `<head>`, so the function exists before you're trying to call it.